# Add a non-dynamic phrase/character after a page title?

Tags: menus, page-template, title

I have a client that has an idea to add a coma after the main page title. Sure, this sounds simple to do-but it makes the navigation see 'WELCOME,' as well. Basically I am adding a phrase in the same font as the title- in a separate div on the page itself, appearing as though it is a new line.

All alternative ways I have thought about this have fail. I tried a simple programing backslash (/') to hide from the php, but it did not work.

In theory I could create a template just for this page and statically add a coma after the php code... concatenate the coma after. ('?> . ,'), but that seems like too much work. Anyone have any ideas?

Better idea, here is what I have:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Post the relevant code please.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do this using the dashboard, not coding needed. BOOM! :) I was over thinking this.

Step 1:

Go to the page in the dashboard and edit the title to what you want. Update the page.

[image: I wanted a coma, so:]

Step 2: Goto Appearance>Menus and select the page with the coma in the name and click on the down arrow on the left, delete the coma (or whatever it is). Finally, save the menu by hitting the save menu blue button on the top-right.

[image: Blue button is beyond the top-right scope of this capture.]

It is important to save the menu and vola! It works :) I do not want the coma in my navigation.